# Accessing a variable in the body of a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I'm trying to implement form objects in my application, using [Muffin](https://github.com/nerdgeschoss/muffin).

In my controller, I do this:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @form = MyForm.new
  end
end
```

Where `MyForm` is a form object, like so:

```rb
class MyForm < Muffin::Base
  attribute :my_attribute
end
```

What I would like to do is essentially this:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @form = MyForm.new(array_of_attribute_names)
  end
end
```

So that when instantiating `MyForm`, I could do something along the lines of:

```rb
class MyForm < Muffin::Base
  array_of_attribute_names.each do |name|
    attribute name
  end
end
```

I know that the above does not work and that it betrays a lack of understanding of Ruby's OO model. Is there a way I can achieve an equivalent effect?

Comment: Do you need the list to be dynamic?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `dry-rb` ecosystem, especially the `dry-validation` gem https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/1.0/ https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-schema/ It does maybe something similar and is a heavily maintained gem, just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could overload the initialize method. Something like this should work, but you might have to tweak the argument structure to accommodate the  `Muffin` base class:

```
class MyForm < Muffin::Base
  def initialize(options = {})
    if options[:array_of_attribute_names].present?
      options[:array_of_attribute_names].each do |attribute_name|
        attribute attribute_name
      end
    end
    super
  end
end
```

and then:

```
@form = MyForm.new(array_of_attribute_names: array_of_attribute_names)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a little easier to do `def initialize(options = [])`? (The OP doesn't seem to indicate that anything other than the `array_of_attribute_names` will be passed in.) If sticking with the hash being passed in, wouldn't you be able to do `if options[:array_of_attribute_names]` - which would be nil or not? If going with an array passed in, wouldn't you be able to do away with the `if` condition altogether?

Comment: That would work as well. I'm just going with the options hash convention. I just figured OP could use that key and pass an array as the value.

Comment: Thank you for answering, unfortunately this does not work—see my comment on jvillian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to riff on the answer provided by NM Pennypacker...

If you want to do:

```
@form = MyForm.new(array_of_attribute_names: array_of_attribute_names)
```

Then it seems like you could do:

```
class MyForm < Muffin::Base
  def initialize(options={})
    class_eval do 
      options[:array_of_attribute_names].each do |attribute_name|
        attribute attribute_name
      end if options[:array_of_attribute_names]
    end
    super
  end
end
```

If you want to stick with the way you outline in your question:

```
@form = MyForm.new(array_of_attribute_names)
```

Then it seems like you could do:

```
class MyForm < Muffin::Base
  def initialize(options=[])
    class_eval do 
      options.each do |attribute_name|
        attribute attribute_name
      end
    end
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, I get a `undefined method 'attribute' for #<MyForm:0x00007f9f88550530>` error when I try this. I _think_ that's because `#attribute` is [defined](https://github.com/nerdgeschoss/muffin/blob/5c055d5a668506ab41a869e5ca9d6031d32dc2cb/lib/muffin/frostings/attributes.rb#L9) as a class method, which makes it available on `MyForm` (an instance of `Class`), but not on any instance of `MyForm`. Can I somehow access this method in this context?

Comment: I'm afraid using `class_eval` means I'm back to square one, as I can now access the method, but I no longer have the `options` hash at my disposal.

Comment: I don't know what 'no longer have the options hash at my disposal' means. Say more, please. You can, after all, simply assign it to an instance variable and be on your way. What, exactly, is it you wish to do with the options other than what describe in your original question?